# Why does the replica work replace in c++?

Tags: c++

I started learning C ++ and my task is to replace some characters in the text. Something similar to the template Here are some examples:

```
<h1>Title</h1>$ js $<p>text...</p>
```

result:

```
<h1>Title</h1> </script>alert(1)</script> <p>text...</p>
```

I tried to do it with this code, but nothing worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string text = "<h1>Title</h1>$ js $<p>text...</p>";
    string js_code = " </script>alert(1)</script> ";

    string result = text.replace(text.find("$ js $"), js_code.length(), js_code);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
<h1>Title</h1> </script>alert(1)</script>
```

The text was inserted into the line, but everything after this text disappeared. Also, sometimes I will use Russian characters, and they are in UTF-8 encoding. 1 Symbol weighs more.

Comment: What does "1 symbol weights more" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `std::string::replace(size_type pos, size_type count,                       const basic_string& str);` is the

> length of the substring that is going to be replaced

e.g. how many characters should be removed after `pos` and before inserting `str`. You want to replace just 6 characters. Your code should look like this:

```
std::string pattern = "$ js $";
std::string result = text.replace(text.find(pattern), pattern.length(), js_code);
```

On another note you should check if `find` returns a valid index before using it.

Comment: text.find(): 14
js_code.length(): 28
You can tell which code will be the solution

Comment: @DimaTverdoy I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.